# Django ManifestFileStorage STATIC_ROOT misconfigured

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, static-files, django-storage

I recently upgraded my project from Django 2.2.28 to 3.2 and am using Django-storage 1.14.2. As part of the upgrade, I replaced CachedFileMixin with ManifestFileStorage. Before the upgrade, everything was functioning correctly, and I haven't altered any other settings.

However, I've run into an issue where self.location seems to cache a None value and it doesn't change. I found a temporary workaround by deleting the cache, which resolves the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any ideas on why this is happening?

Code Snippet:

```
class StaticFilesStorage(ManifestStaticFilesStorage, S3Boto3Storage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        S3Boto3Storage.__init__(self, bucket_name=settings.STATIC_FILES_BUCKET, custom_domain=domain(settings.STATIC_URL), *args, **kwargs)
        ManifestStaticFilesStorage.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Error Message:
[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT9D9.png)
PDB Output:
[PDB output in ManifestStaticFilesStorage initializing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTGP9.png)
After refreshing the cached value manually the error is resolved